# External Content Type Connection : illegal operation attempted on a registry key marked for deletion

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

when I add a connection to a sql server database in an external content type from Sharepoint Designer 2013 I get this error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BDEADDF26....} failed due to the following error: 800703fa illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion
```

I see that CLSID corresponds to

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\OWSSVR.DLL

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do an IISRESET on your SharePoint servers to check if it solves this issue.

If this issue still exists, you can try to disable the related Windows User Profile Service feature.

Some similar threads for your reference:

[BDC Service Application Error on Deletion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f99c246-2217-4645-b28b-2c4164546307/bdc-service-application-error-on-deletion?forum=sharepointgeneral)

["800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key" error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-sg/sharepoint/support/server-admin/800703fa-Illegal-operation-error)

[COM: Intermittent error 800703fa: Illegal Operation attempted on a registry key](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/03/01/com-intermittent-error-800703fa-illegal-operation-attempted-on-a-registry-key/)